# Почему выдаёт ошибку при использовании react-dropzone при попытке передать туда какие-либо настройки

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-типы

При использовании библиотеки react-dropzone версии "^14.2.3", при попытке передать в функцию `useDropzone()`

(
Версия typescript: "^5.2.2"
Версия react: "^18.2.0"
)

useDropzone какие-либо настройки выдёт ошибку:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ onDrop: (files: any) => void; noClick: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DropzoneOptions'.
  Type '{ onDrop: (files: any) => void; noClick: boolean; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>, PropTypes>': multiple, onDragEnter, onDragOver, onDragLeave
```

На том же компьютере в другом проекте такой проблемы нет, насколько я понял, ошибка заключается именно в типе 'Pick<React.HTMLProps, PropTypes>'

Вот мой код:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";

interface IDropzoneProps {
    maxFiles: number;
}

export default function Dropzone(props: IDropzoneProps) {
    function onDrop(files: any) {

    }

    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, open } = useDropzone({
        onDrop: (files) => onDrop(files),
        noClick: false,
        maxFiles: props.maxFiles,
        accept: {
            'image/png': ['.png'],
            'image/jpg': ['.jpg'],
            'image/jpeg': ['.jpeg']
        }
    });


    return <div className="dropzone-container">
        <div {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone-area" })} >
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            {isDragActive && <div className="darkness-mask" />}

            <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                {isDragActive ? <h3 className="dropzone-main-text">Отлично, а теперь отспусти мышку</h3>
                    : <><h3 className="dropzone-main-text noselect">Перетащите изображение в эту область</h3>
                        <h4 className="dropzone-comment-text noselect">или выберете файл из проводника</h4></>
                }
            </div>

            <button className="btn btn-primary dropzone-choose-file-button">Выбрать файл</button>

        </div>
    </div>

};
```

Пытался решить проблему, но так и не понял что ещё нужно передать что-бы ошибка пропала?